# Loss of data in a FIFO pipe?

Tags: python, c++, ipc, fifo

I have a python process writing to a named pipe, and a C++ program reads it. (I create the pipes in C++). Well, it seems to work fine. However, sometimes I notice that there's loss of data. The data is not detected by the reader! Am I doing something wrong?

Here's how I am creating the pipes:

```
void create_pipes(string pipename){

    char * cstr1 = new char [pipename.length()+1];
    strcpy (cstr1, pipename.c_str());

    cout << "Creating " << pipename << " pipe..." << endl;
    unlink (cstr1); // Delete pipe
    int result = mkfifo (cstr1, S_IRUSR| S_IWUSR);  // Create Pipe
    if( result == -1 ){
         cout << "There was en error creating the pipe! " << result << endl;
         //return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Pipe created!" << endl;
}
```

Now, I have a thread that reads the pipe like this:

```
     int fd = open(cstr1, O_RDONLY);  // Open the pipe


    while( running_threads ){

        if(!read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF))
            continue;
        string line(buf);
        if( buf != "" ){
            //cout << line;
            pipe_r.DECODE_PIPE_DATA(line);
        }
    }

    cout << "Thread terminated" << endl;

    close(fd);
```

In python I'm simply writing the data to the pipe by doing this:

```
def write_pipe(file_string):
    while True:
        try:
            pipe.write(file_string)
            pipe.flush()
            break
        except:
            print "Error while writing to pipe"
            continue
```

What could be causing my problem? The python program writes the data into the pipe successfully; But the c++ program sometimes will not read the pipe. Can this be caused by the python process writing data faster than the c++ program before it could actually read it? What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Tangent: why not just pass `pipename.c_str()` to `unlink` and `mkfifo`? The code as you've written it needlessly allocates memory (and then forgets to deallocate it).

Comment: `if(!read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF))` -- You throw away the result of `read`, so you have no idea how much data you read. There's no possible way the code could work.

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is not guaranteed to be terminated, nor is it guaranteed to not have `'\0'` characters embedded in it from the code you posted.  This should work better, but may still fail if the Python code embeds a `'\0'` in the data it writes:

```
while( running_threads )
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    if ( bytesRead < 0 )
         break;
    else if ( bytesRead == 0 )
         continue;

    string line( buf, static_cast<size_t>(bytesRead) );
```

And your code doesn't properly handle an error condition should `read()` return -1.

Comment: This should work even if there are embedded nulls. A `std::string` can contain arbitrary data.

Comment: @Brian, True.  But the constructor he's using assumes a C-style string is the input data. (I'm admittedly assuming `buf` is defined as `char *` or `char []`.)

Comment: I mean, your code uses the correct constructor, so it doesn't suffer from the same problem. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I used the constructor that specifies the length of the input string.  I don't recall offhand what happens if a `'\0'` is embedded in such a string with that constructor.  That's why I said it "may still fail".  But it does prevent overruns, which the original code did not.  Per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/, the `string( const char *, size_t )` constructor copies the specified number of bytes.  So it should work.  But I don't remember ever using that constructor.

Comment: So just to be clear... my python code should not send the '\0' character?